# Find all string in 2d array like template

Tags: c#, linq

I have a 2d array - `List<List<string>>`, this array has 3 columns.

I want find in second column of all rows this string template - `192:19:6_different_numbers:some_numbers_or_symbols` or `192:24:6_different_numbers:some_numbers_or_symbols`.

For example - 192:24:123456:5432

Comment: Please add proper examples.

Comment: You want to check only second column?

Comment: 192:24:123456:123a or 192:19:123456:123a or 192:24:777777:1244444

Comment: yes only second column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex to match your patter, my regex may not be complete (i have no ide here to try it out)

```
List<List<string>> myStuff = ...;
Regex regex = new Regex("192:(24|19):[0-9]{6}:[0-9A-Za-z]*")
var matchingRows = myStuff.Where(x => regex.IsMatch(x[1]);
```

Comment: thk, but in the second position maybe 24 or 19 , how to change this regular expresion? Or i need use two regular expression - one for 24 in second position and other for 19 in second position?

Comment: @Console: You don't need an IDE for testing regex. This are my two favourite tools: http://regex101.com and https://www.debuggex.com

Comment: but linq is not working, try `var matchingRows = myStuff.Where(x => regex.IsMatch(x[1]).ToList();`, but matchingRows have 0 rows

Comment: i can't help you here. the regex is working (and the linq is working aswell) maybe your column is not x[i]. I assumed that your List<List<string>> is a List of Rows on the outer level and ever string item represents a column. have you considered replacing the List<List<string>> with string[columnCount,3] ? which would represent a your datastructure better.

Comment: And if i want array with rows that not like this template - somethink like "NOT LIKE" in sql

Comment: myStuff.Where(x => !regex.IsMatch(x[1]); Please spend some time in research before asking the NOT Operator '!' should be known.